# AngularJS Input Date field

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form for a user to update his/her information. One of the fields is for their Date of Birth (DOB) that it is autopopulated from the database.
The problem is that if the user doesn't need to update the DOB and since the DOB is a required field the form validation thinks that it is blank and it forces to user to interact or update the field.
This is the current code:

```html
<input type="date" name="dob" ng-model="profileData.dob" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row["dob"]; ?>" ng-init="profileData.dob='<?php echo $row["dob"]; ?>'" />
```

So what I did is that I updated the code by adding ng-change. This will allow the form to be submitted. The problem with this is that if the user really needs to update the DOB it will not update. It will keep whatever is showing in the field value:

```html
<input type="date" name="dob" ng-model="profileData.dob" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row["dob"]; ?>" ng-init="profileData.dob='<?php echo $row["dob"]; ?>'" ng-change="profileData.dob='<?php echo $row["dob"]; ?>'" />
```

How do I change the input date field so that it works correctly when it doesn't need to be updated and also works well when it needs to be updated?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scgvns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in a very simple way:

HTML:

`<input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" ng-model="profileData.dob" class="form-control" ng-init="profileData.dob" />`

Js:

`$scope.profileData = {
  dob: new Date('<?php echo $row["dob"]; ?>')
};`